# Cannot find symbol for previously named variable

Tags: java, find, symbols

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class V1_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner UIS = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Hello!");
        System.out.println("    What is my name?");
        String MyName = UIS.nextLine();
        while(true){
            String a1 = UIS.nextLine();
            execute(a1);
        }
    }
    public static void execute(String a1) {
        Scanner UIS = new Scanner(System.in);
        switch(a1) {
            case "Hello":
                System.out.println("    Hello!");
                break;
            case "What is your name?":
                System.out.println("My name is " + MyName + )
            case "SHUTDOWN":
                System.out.print("  Goodbye...");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("    I don't understand...");
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to compile this code, i get an error stating that it cannot find the symbol MyName even though it would be previously named. I am very new to java (last night), so any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Read up on _scope of declarations_.

Comment: You pass a1 as an argument to execute, but you also need to pass MyName.

Comment: Ok, i understand now. I cant find anywhere how to execute multiple variables such as MyName and a1 both.

Answer (score 0):

In the exact case you have... To make **MyName** local variable be accessible by two methods at a time you may incapsulate it or declare **MyName** as a field;

*Declaring as a field example:*

```
private static String MyName;//do declare as a field
public class V1_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner UIS = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Hello!");
        System.out.println("    What is my name?");
        MyName = UIS.nextLine();//<--do not declare but init only
        while(true){
            String a1 = UIS.nextLine();
            execute(a1);
        }
    }
    public static void execute(String a1) {
        Scanner UIS = new Scanner(System.in);
        switch(a1) {
            case "Hello":
                System.out.println("    Hello!");
                break;
            case "What is your name?":
                System.out.println("My name is " + MyName + )
            case "SHUTDOWN":
                System.out.print("  Goodbye...");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default :
                System.out.println("    I don't understand...");
        }
    }
}
```

*p.s. I declared the field **MyName** as **static** cause "non static variable cannot be reference from static context"*

Anyways please read tutorials more carefully :)

---

If you have more details please do comment

Good luck :)

Comment: This worked and your explanation helped immensely. Thank you. I will be looking into more tutorials more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

First of all, the code is not as good as it could be. Personally, I would split all of the cases into their own methods.

Second, you should pick a better name for the class, preferably a noun, and you should not make all methods static. The static keyword should be avoided in most cases.

For the purposes of the following code, I will assume that the class is called Thingy (Feel free to edit with a better name).

To use non static methods, you must first create a Thingy object by using the snippet `Thingy thing = new Thingy();`

That snippet creates a Thingy reference variable called thingy, and initializes it to a new instance of a Thingy object.

That way, you will be able to declare an Instance variable by inserting `String MyName;` outside of a method, and be able to access it in all non static methods.

To access it in main, after you've declared a Thingy object, access the reference variable IN MAIN by using thing.MyName, e.g. `thing.MyName = UIS.nextLine();`

In a non static method, all instance variables can be accessed like local variables, e.g. `MyName = "Chris";`

For advice from people who are better than this than me, read the Official Tutorial.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/